# While not new line

Tags: c++, file, newline, fstream

if i have a file like

```
1 5 6 9 7 1 
2 5 4 3 8 9
3 4 3 2 1 6
4 1 3 6 5 4
```

and i want to sort the numbers in every line ..
how to know when there is a newline ?
code for example :

```
while (!input.eof) {
    input>>num;
    while (not new line ?){
    input>>o;
    b.push_back(o);
    }
    sort (b.begin(),b.end());
    se=b.size();
    output<<num<<" "<<b[se-1]<<endl;
    b.clear();
}
```

Note: i tried while(input>>num) and getline will now work with me
any ideas ?

Comment: If you want to read lines, your best bet is going to be `getline`. Note that [`while (!eof())` is wrong.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: Since it looks like you are iterating over every character individually, you might find it helpful to know that `"\n"` is the `CHAR` for a new line.

Comment: Why eof is wrong? Std::getline itself does move the file towards the end

Comment: @Gasim, click on the link that chris provided to see why `while (!eof())` is "wrong". More specifically, it's not a good way to check this kind of loop since one must attempt to read the EOF before `eof()` is true. It doesn't tell you if you are "at" the EOF.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::getline` together with `std::istringstream` to read the file line by line, and then process each line individually:

```
#include <sstream>
std::string line;
while (std::getline(infile, line))
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    int a, b;
    //You can now read the numbers in the current line from iss
}
```

For further reference on how to read the file line by line, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868936/c-read-file-line-by-line).

Answer (score 1):

Your input doesn't work! Using a loop testing for `stream.eof()` as the only control for the input is always wrong. You always need to test your input **after** you tried to read it. Incidentally, I posted earlier how you can guarantee that there is no newline between to objects. there is already an answer using `std::getline()` as a first stage which is somewhat boring. Here is an alternate approach:

```
std::istream& noeol(std::istream& in) {
    for (int c; (c = in.peek()) != std::char_traits<char>::eof()
             && std::isspace(c); in.get()) {
        if (c == '\n') {
            in.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
        }
    }
    return in;
}

// ...

while (input >> num) {
    do {
        b.push_back(num);
    } while (input >> noeol >> num);
    std::sort (b.begin(),b.end());
    se=b.size();
    output<<num<<" "<<b[se-1]<<endl;
    b.clear();
    input.clear();
}
```